# How can List<...Model> implement using Vue.js?

Tags: c#, .net, vue.js, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC app, and I try read data from Vue.js.

How can you implement the `List<LogMessageModel>`?

Controller

```
public class LoggingController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly ILoggingService _loggingService;

    public LoggingController(IMapper mapper, ILoggingService loggingService)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _loggingService = loggingService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var dtos = _loggingService.GetAllLogMessages();

        var model = _mapper.Map<List<LogMessageDto>, List<LogMessageModel>>(dtos);

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View

```
@model List<LogBerichtModel>
...
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
</head>
        <body>
        <div id="app">
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="message in logMessages">
                        ... data from logMessages...
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <script src="~/js/app.js"></script>
        </div>
        
        </body>
```

Vue.Js

```
    const app = Vue.createApp({
         // data, functions
        data() {
            return {
                // How to read data List<LogMessageModel>?
                LogMessages: @Html.Raw(@Json.Serialize(List<LogMessageModel>)),
            }
        },
        methods: {
    
        },
        computed: {
        }
    })

app.mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

### Quick example (adapt and improve to your use case):

`Controller`

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //list of something
    var foo = new List<ErrorViewModel>
    {
       new ErrorViewModel {RequestId = "1", Message = "message 1"},
       new ErrorViewModel {RequestId = "2", Message = "message 2"},
       new ErrorViewModel {RequestId = "3", Message = "message 3"},
     };

    return View(foo);
}
```

---

`View` + `Vue.js`

`data.logs` is serialized directly to `Razor` view (`HTML` doc) instead of another/additional client-side http request (axios, fetch, etc), which you can do (unnecessary **in this sample/simple case**).

However, depending on use case, you'll need to provide an (api) endpoint for `Vue` to call (axios, fetch, etc) to extend this (updates to data, etc) without reloading (a `SPA`)

```html
@model List<ErrorViewModel>

@*Load Vue in a predefined (by you) RenderSectionAsync in _Layout template, this goes to head of HTML doc...*@
@section HeadScripts
{
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
}


<div>
    <h2>Server side</h2>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li>@item.RequestId: @item.Message</li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>



<div>
    <h2>Vue (client side)</h2>
    <div id="app">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="log in logs">Request Id: {{log.requestId}} | Message: {{log.message}}</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>


@*Another section you define in _Layout template - this renders at bottom of HTML doc*@
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        const app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                logs: @Json.Serialize(Model) //array                
            }

        });
    </script>
}
```

---

Hth...

Comment: Thank you. I'll tried it as your second solution. Maybe I have to read the data as first one. (The solution I know). And I have to use Vue-script just for the events.